# check boxes are not aligned properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I want to make some thing like this

[image]

Trying following code but in view layouts are not properly aligned can someone help me out with this.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtServices"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Services "
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Dine In" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Take Away" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Home Delivery" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="BYO" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Bar" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Gluten Free" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService7"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Vegan" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Vegiterian" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/chkService9"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Organic" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Try to align all check boxes properly to get view as shown. I have tried with managing vertical layouts but not helping.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of result you get?

Comment: Set every Checkbox's width to 0dip

Comment: use [TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for this

Comment: Thanks all but changing parent lay orientation to horizontal and changing inner layout to vertical done the trick for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtServices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Services "
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Dine In"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Take Away"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Home Delivery"
                android:textSize="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="BYO" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Bar" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Gluten Free" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Vegan" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Vegiterian" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="Organic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: See this]

Answer (score 2):

You should use 0dp as width when you use Weight property:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtServices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Services "
        android:textSize="22dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Dine In" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Take Away" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Home Delivery" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="BYO" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService5"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Bar" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService6"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Gluten Free" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService7"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Vegan" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService8"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Vegiterian" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkService9"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Organic" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.